# Checking a RSS Feeds List Periodically Into the iOS Background

Tags: ios, background, rss

I'm trying to check periodically a RSS feeds list into the iOS background. How can I launch a method par example every ten minutes, once the app did enter into the background? Can I do it using local notifications?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't. iOS doesn't allow this kind of background processes. Some people have tried to use workarounds like playing silent music in the background but this is against the App Store rules and apps have been rejected by Apple if caught.

Comment: Therefore, I have to use the Apple Push Notification Service (APNS)?

Comment: Push notifications cannot execute any code or launch your app without user interaction, either.

Comment: This app is like an RSS reader, I have to check an RSS feeds list periodically to know when news are published. Like this I can alert the user about it. How can I check periodically the RSS feeds list even when the app is into the background?

Comment: Even if you don't like my answer, it still remains true. It's not possible to do this client-side. Do it on your own server if you want to but then it's not a question about iOS anymore.

Comment: Can you link me somewhere to read about do this using my own server?

Comment: @OleBegemann : Is this still the case?  I have an app called Chime that speaks the time based upon some parameters.  How is it waking to do that if this is prohibited?